# HP Pavilion DV4 laptop fan always running at high speed

Tags: fan, hp-pavilion

A few days back I had a display problem with my HP Pavilion DV4 laptop. I took it to a service centre and they told me that some NVIDIA chip on the motherboard needed to be replaced to fix this.

After replacing the chip, the display problem was fixed but the fan started running at high speeds – even if there were no application running. The fan is noisy, its speed does not drop even little bit but remains running while I use the laptop.

When I asked the service centre guy, he said the reason was the new NVIDIA chip etc. What could be the cause of this problem?

Is it because of the new NVIDIA chip installed on motherboard? Could it be something different?

Comment: How are your CPU temperatures? Are you sure it's not overheating?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen some Dells that had this resolved in  BIOS update.  Is the BIOS current?

As noted, use someting like [Speedfan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) to check temperatures.  Is there any buildup of dust around any of the fans? If you can, check any screws holding heat sinks to assure good contact,